# Error {% trans %} in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, translate, django-sitetree

I have a django template that I want to translate a value that is variable, since it is inside a for.

The line is the following: {{item.title}} I want to translate what is inside that variable of the template.

What I did was {{{% trans 'item.title'%}}} and then in the django.po file the following:

```
#: templates/tittle.html:10 (line where the variable to be translated)
msgid "Tittle"
msgstr "Titulo"

#: templates/tittle.html:10
msgid "Tittle2"
msgstr "Titulo2"
```

And so for all the case of for. This does not work for me So I ask what I'm doing wrong, or if there is some other way to do it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Use `{% trans item.title %}`. Note however that it is rather strange to do this, since `title` can be anything, and thus *not* per se translatable.

Comment: If your `item` is a model instance, you definitly want to handle the translation in the database at the model level (there are a couple generic django apps for this, pick the one that best fits your needs). If it's a transiant object (dict or whatever) created in the view (or in code called by the view) the translation should really be handled in the part of the python code that creates this object. TL;DR: you should not translate variables in templates unless you really have no other choice.

Answer (score 0):

Like specified in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag), you  can specify a variable in a `{% trans .. %}` tag, by just omitting the quotes, like:

```
{% trans item.title %}
```

It is however a bit "*unsafe*" in the sense that a title can probably be anything, and is therefore not *per se* translatable. In case there is no translation, Django will default to the original value of `item.title`.